# Solving a system of nonlinear (quadratic) equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms

Consider the following system of equations:
$$\begin{align}
(x + 1)^2 [(p - l)^2 + (q - m)^2] &= (a - l)^2 + (b - m)^2 \\
(x + 1)^2 [(p - a)^2 + (q - b)^2] &= x^2[(a - l)^2 + (b - m)^2]\end{align}$$
Find the value of $p$ and $q$ in terms of $a, b, x, l$ and $m$, provided that $x > 0$.

Comment: Try to divide second equation to the first one. I checked in Mathematica, this system has single solution and it's short and nice.

Comment: what is the answer, then? please tell me, I don't have mathematica yet.

Comment: Kaster gave you the very good hint ! Show your efforts, please. If you have problem, tell us where you are stuck and a lot of people will be helping you.

Comment: Actually, I'm not showing my efforts because they are very lengthy

Comment: I sware that, if you do what Kaster gave you, it is pretty simple (even simpler that what is given in the good answers you received). Come on ! Cheers :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I can't solve this using by paper and pen, even by Kaster's method, How do you sware that it's pretty simple. Please tell me post your answer I assure you I'll upvote your question and will choose your answer correct if it's simple. Please tell me your attempt. I tried for half an hour, and doesn't get success, please answer.

Comment: I did by hand what Kaster suggested and I am almost blind ! It took me ten minutes or even less.

Comment: can you please post your attempt? because I'm unable to solve honestly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16100/discussion-between-user91374-and-claude-leibovici).

Comment: I have to go now. But, in any manner, I would prefer that Kaster be involved. All the merit is his !

Comment: but please tell me your method.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Please post your answer, I'm feeling very uncomfortable. I've divided 2nd equation from 1st equation. Then, the RHS became $x^2$ then I've simplified LHS, but how to proceed then??

Comment: @user91374 sorry for delay. I haven't solved this problem. I just suggest that dividing one to another might make it a bit easier. Based on Claude's answer, it is somewhat solvable. I was too lazy to solve by hands and so just fed it to the Mathematica, which provided the following answer:
$$
p = \frac {a + lx}{1 + x} \\
q = \frac {b + mx}{1+x}
$$

Comment: @Kaster thank you, really. Actually, I don't have mathematica. But for the sake of information, I am asking. Does Mathematica provide step by step solution?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
Divide both equations by $(x+1)^2$ and set
$$\alpha^2 =  \frac{(a - l)^2 + (b - m)^2}{(x+1)^2} \quad \beta^2 = \frac{x^2[(a - l)^2 + (b - m)^2]}{(x+1)^2},$$
then the system of equations to solve becomes
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
(p - l)^2 + (q - m)^2 &=& \alpha^2 \\
(p - a)^2 + (q - b)^2 &=& \beta^2
\end{array}\right.$$
I.e. you have to find the [intersection of two circles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) in the plane. One of these circle has center $c_1 = (l,m)$ and radius $r_1 = \alpha$ while the other has center $c_2 = (a,b)$ and radius $r_2=\beta$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my semi-geometrical solution. Let's scale $p$ and $q$ to $1+x$. So
$$
P = p(1+x) \\
Q = q(1+x)
$$
so equation become
\begin{align}
\left [P-(x+1)l \right ]^2 + \left [Q-(x+1)m \right ]^2 &= (a-l)^2 + (b-m)^2 \\
\left [P-(x+1)a \right ]^2 + \left [Q-(x+1)b \right ]^2 &= x^2 \left [ (a-l)^2 + (b-m)^2 \right ]
\end{align}
So, geometrical part now. The problem above is to find intersection points of two circles. Obviously circles might intersect at zero points (don't intersect), one point (tangent to each other), two points (real intersection) and infinite number of points (coinciding circles). Circle number one has a center at $[(x+1)l, (x+1)m]$ and a radius of $r = \sqrt{(a-l)^2 + (b-m)^2}$. Circle number two has a center of $[(x+1)a, (x+1)b]$ and a radius of $R = \sqrt{x^2 \left [ (a-l)^2 + (b-m)^2 \right ]} = rx$. Now, observe that distance between centers is $d = \sqrt{(x+1)^2 \left [ (a-l)^2 + (b-m)^2 \right ]} = (x+1)r = r + R$. So, the only possibility to those two circles is to be tangent to each other. Diagram is below

[image]

It is obvious now, that tangent point divides the line that connects the centers in $1:x$ proportion. So
$$
P = (x+1)l + 1 \cdot (a-l) = a + xl \\
Q = (x+1)m + 1 \cdot (b -m) = b + xm
$$
Going back to $p$ and $q$, you can easily find that 
$$
\left \{ \begin{array}{ccc}
p & = & \frac {a + xl}{1 + x} \\
q & = & \frac {b + xm}{1 + x}
\end{array} \right .
$$

Comment: Thanx, really, I want to know that how you get this idea?

Comment: @user91374 well, main part is to scale $p$ and $q$. I decide to do so after doing some ``cheating'' :). I already knew the solution by using mathematica and I just observed that both $p$ and $q$ had a common denominator of $1+x$. So I multiplied to it to see if equations get simplified. They did and also revealed simple geometry with obvious centers location and relation between radii. I'm not sure if I would do that without knowing the solution beforehand.

Comment: Oh, yes! I forgotten you used Mathematica... Despite you made  a very good observation. I also made an observation just now!, It is that, p and q are same as Section formula, isn't it?

Comment: @user91374 exactly. I actually used the same, just a bit shorter version of it.

Comment: Okay, I'm satisfied from your answer and your method thank you very much for that, really. But for the sake of curiosity, what was Claude talking about? He said he solved this equations using your hint : Divide second equation by the first one, and he got the answer within ten minutes, I tried and simplified for half an hour, I got nothing than lengthy expressions, how did he? Have you any idea? Please, Check in mathematica if possible.

Comment: @user91374 have no idea. Not that I spent a lot of time on it, but moving terms around didn't lead me anywhere. If you solve those equations in Mathematica and don't do full simplification, solution for the $q$ looks so ugly involving squares. But I don't completely reject the idea that there is some algebraically clever solution which is quite simple too. BTW, I think mvw is moving in that direction. He just didn't finish it up. I'm sure after all algebra's done, he should get the same answer. So give him some credit too.

Comment: Kaster did spend the time to look at the one point solution closer and his graphics is very nice for this. I did not isolate that situation which should somehow show up in the lengthy solutions, giving a reason why not two but one solutions, e.g. by cancelling root sub terms. I tried instead to work in vector representation, location vector plus r times unit sphere vector but that results in statements of sine and cosine functions with different amplitudes and angles where one needs to decide if they have common points which I can only do by plotting them and not by looking at values alone.

Comment: The fact that we share answers and comments allows improvement not unlike traditional publishing.

Comment: @Kaster. Very elegant geometric analysis ! Thanks for providing it. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, But how did you solve by hands within ten minutes! please tell us, I'm very curious to know about your method.I'm begging you for many days, please tell me.

Comment: Hey @user91374, why would you uncheck this as a solution?

Comment: Sorry mate, but I've found an short algebraic solution - (with no use of geometry) by hand, which I found to be more elegant, I 'll post it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

The right hand sides just differ by a factor $x^2 > 0$:
$$
\begin{align}
(x + 1)^2 [(p - l)^2 + (q - m)^2] &= (a - l)^2 + (b - m)^2 \\
(x + 1)^2 [(p - a)^2 + (q - b)^2] &= x^2[(a - l)^2 + (b - m)^2]
\end{align}
$$

so we can get an equation for the left hand sides:
$$
\begin{align}
(x + 1)^2 [(p - l)^2 + (q - m)^2] &=
\frac{(x + 1)^2}{x^2} [(p - a)^2 + (q - b)^2] \iff \\
[(p - l)^2 + (q - m)^2] &=
\frac{1}{x^2} [(p - a)^2 + (q - b)^2] \quad (*)
\end{align}
$$

and indeed if we call the left side of $(*)$ $r_1^2$ and $x^2$ times the right side $r_2^2$
we got two circle equations in coordinates $p$ and $q$
$$
\begin{align}
(p - l)^2 + (q - m)^2 &= r_1^2 \\
(p - a)^2 + (q - b)^2 & = r_2^2
\end{align}
$$

where $r_1 = \sqrt{(a-l)^2+(b-m)^2}\, / \, (1 + x)$, $r_2 = x \, r_1$ and the first circle has radius radius $r_1$, origin $(l, m)$ and the second circle has radius $r_2$, origin $(a, b)$.

So the system can have the following solutions:

- no solution: the two circles do not intersect, e.g. both origin $(0,0)$ and $r_1 \ne r_2$
- one solution: the two circles intersect at just one point
- two solutions: the two circles intersect in two points
- infinite solutions: the two circles are congruent (same origin, same radius)

This gives
$$
p = l \pm \sqrt{r_1^2 - (q -m)^2} = a \pm \sqrt{r_2^2 - (q - b)^2} \quad (**)
$$
For $l = a$ this reduces to
$$
r_1^2 - (q -m)^2 = r_2^2 - (q - b)^2
$$
which gives
$$
q = \frac{b^2-m^2+r_1^2-r_2^2}{2(b-m)}
$$
for $b \ne m$ otherwise this reduces to 
$$
r_1 = r_2 \iff x = 1
$$
for $b = m$.

For $l \ne a$ the calculation gets lengthy, throwing it into a computer algebra system (here WolframAlpha) gives 
[this result](http://tinyurl.com/l6xheoo).

Once one knows $q$ one can use one of the equations $(**)$ to calculate $p$.