# Non-linear equation system Resolution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to prove (I am not sure it is true though) that

$$\left\{\begin{array}{c} x-y-x\left( x^2+5y^2\right)=0\\ x+y-y\left( x^2+y^2\right) =0\end{array}\right.$$

Admits no other solution in the plane than the origin.

==================================================================

I tried:

Let's consider $ \left( x,y\right)\in \mathbb{R}^2-\{  \left( 0,0\right)\} $

$y\neq0$ otherwise $x=0$

So I can change second equation as such:
$$ x^2+y^2= \frac{x+y}{y} $$
But that does not lead me anywhere actually.

Comment: I used mathematica, it shows that this system of equations have only one real solution which you have mentioned (0,0). So, your doubt about the solution of this system of equations is cleared. But, now we have to show this eqauation doesn't yield any other real solution. But How you found this problem?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I was given this system and asked to solve it in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Please don't mind dude, Can you please tell me How you find this problem?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. This is the wording of a math problem I have to solve. The system is given as such and I must solve it in the real plane. What more would you like to know?

Comment: Sorry dude, I just wanted to know that if you have found this problem independently during studying some other matter in mathematics, as I have found a problem during study of section formula in analytic geometry - posted on this page .http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883486/solving-a-system-of-nonlinear-quadratic-equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have tried $x^2+y^2= \frac{x+y}{y}$, and then I tried, $x^2+5y^2=\frac{x-y}{x}$.. Now, from that I 've found $y^2=-\frac{x^2+y^2}{4xy}$. But $x^2+y^2>0$[assuming $\left( x,y\right)\in \mathbb{R}^2-\{  \left( 0,0\right)\}$]. So, $xy>0$. 
So, $x>0 \leftrightarrow y>0$ and $x<0 \leftrightarrow y<0$

Now, remark that $x^2+5y^2>x^2+y^2$. So, $\frac{x-y}{x}>\frac{x+y}{y}$. 
Now, we have two cases : $(1)x>0$ and $y>0$ (2)$x<0$ and $y<0$

Consider first case, 
$\frac{x-y}{x}>\frac{x+y}{y}$
$xy-y^2>xy+x^2$
$x^2+y^2<0$... which is not possible.

Now, consider second case, $\frac{x-y}{x}>\frac{x+y}{y}$
$[\frac{x-y}{x}]x<[\frac{x+y}{y}]x$ [because $x<0$]
$[\frac{x-y}{x}]xy>[\frac{x+y}{y}]xy$ [because $y<0$]
$y(x-y)>x(x+y)$
$xy-y^2>x^2+xy$
$x^2+y^2<0$ Which is not possible. So, We have $x=0$ and $y=0$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking for such a solution. Much faster and less error-prone than actually solving multiple quadratic polynomials.

Comment: Yes, but remark that this is not an elegant solution. If you really want to learn mathematics, you should take interest in elegant solutions/